# Error while loading "rgl" package in R on mac os x

Tags: r, osx-mavericks, rgl

I have an error when try to open rgl library:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have XQuartz installed on OSX for rgl to work.